# Pyspark join on multiple aliased table columns

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Python doesn't like the ampersand below.
I get the error:
 `& is not a supported operation for types str and str. Please review your code.`

Any idea how to get this right? I've never tried to join more than 1 column for aliased tables. Thx!!

```
df_initial_sample = df_crm.alias('crm').join(df_cngpt.alias('cng'), on= (("crm.id=cng.id") & ("crm.cpid = cng.cpid")), how = "inner")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using as below -

```
df_initial_sample = df_crm.alias('crm').join(df_cngpt.alias('cng'), on= (["id"] and ["cpid"]), how = "inner")
```

Comment: Hi, I tried that but I get the error 'crm.cp_hier_id = cng.center_hier_id is missing on the left side of the join given schema' The columns I'm joining together do not have the same name, I just put fillers in the prior code. here is the code now, leaving the columns the same name. Does this look right?     '''    df_initial_sample = df_crm.alias('crm').join(df_cngpt.alias('cng'), on= (("crm.uid=cng.empl_uid") and ("crm.cp_id= cng.center_id")), how = "inner") .filter((df_crm.acct == '12345678') & (df_crm.start_dt == '2022-02-24'))'''

Comment: @SPena Can you add your input and expected output datasets as part of your question stem? Hopefully this will provide a better picture about the use case! Additionally, why do you need to `alias` the `dataframes`, as I already can see you are using two separate `dataframes` for join condition.

Comment: Hi, I got it to work without aliasing. I wanted to use aliasing so I didn't have to type the full table name each time I wanted to select columns (there are many)!!

Answer (score 0):

Your join condition is overcomplicated. It can be as simple as this

```py
df_initial_sample = df_crm.join(df_cngpt, on=['id', 'cpid'], how = 'inner')
```